# RustのResultについての質問 error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time

Tags: rust

#### 概略

現在`tmp`ディレクトリをクリーニングする、デーモンを作成しています。そこで、ある程度はRustの理解が深まってきたので、`Result`を使ってエラーハンドリングを試みましたが、ビルドの際にして以下のようなエラーが出ました。

まず第一に`Result`の理解が進んでいない事と、デーモンを組んだ経験が無いので、見通しがつかずコードを組んでいる状態です。ですので、`Result`の扱いと`デーモンの組み方`をセットで質問したいと思います。

伺いたいことは以下の2つです。

- `Result`のエラーはどのようにして解決すべきなのでしょうか？
- またデーモンの組み方とは？

---

**エラーメッセージ**

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:4:16
  |
4 | fn clener() -> Result<str, str>{
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `str`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: required by `std::result::Result`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `tmpcleaner`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

**現状のソースコード** (実験段階のため、かなり汚いコードになっています)

```rust
use std::fs;
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn clener() -> Result<str, str>{
    let killer = fs::remove_dir_all("/tmp");
    let ok = "complete a mission";
    let err  = "missing a mission";

    match killer {        
         Ok(ok) => return Ok(ok), 
         Err(err) => return Err(err),
    }
}

fn main(){
    let localtime = Local::now().format("%H%M%S").to_string();
    let compare = "123000";

    if compare  == localtime {
        println!("Ture");
    }else{    
        println!("False");
    }   

    println!("{}", localtime);
    println!("{}", compare);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

こんにちは。

> `Result` のエラーはどのようにして解決すべきなのでしょうか？

これはいくつかのエラーが複合しているので、1つ1つ解説します。

まずはエラーメッセージそのもの、「the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time」について

`str` を `&'static str` にすれば解決します。 Rustでは勝手にポインタが作られたりしないので `str` は任意長の文字列そのものを表わします。これを関数から返すということは、例えば1000文字の文字列ならば1000文字分のデータをコピーして呼出元に返すことになります。今のところRustは任意長のデータをスタックにコピーする操作は許していません。そこで `&str` とポインタを介すると16バイト（ポインタサイズ8バイト+strのサイズ8バイト）と定サイズになるのでエラーにならなくなります。
「`str` 型を生で使うことはない」と覚えてしまっていいでしょう。

もし、関数内で動的に生成した文字列を返したいなら `String` を使うとよいと思います。`String` は`&str` からも `"str".to_string()` で作れるので現時点でも `String` に移行することができます。
`&str` と `String` については [こちら](https://doc.rust-jp.rs/book/second-edition/ch08-02-strings.html)などを参考にして下さい。

それとは別に、このコードでは返り値型を `Result<String, String>` などにしてもコンパイルは通りません。
以下のコードでは `killer` (`remove_dir_all` の返り値) に対してマッチし、成功した場合、失敗した場合の返り値それぞれに `ok` 、 `err` を束縛しています。そしてそのまま `Ok`、 `Err` に包んで返しています。

```rust
    match killer {
        Ok(ok) => return Ok(ok),
        Err(err) => return Err(err),
    }
```

Rustでは関数の最後の式は `return` 文が必要ないので以下のように書いても同じです。

```rust
    match killer {
        Ok(ok) => Ok(ok),
        Err(err) => Err(err),
    }
```

スコープに `ok` 、 `err` の変数があるので分かりづらいですが、ここでの `ok` 、 `err` は `match` 式で導入した方の `ok` 、 `err` なので、以下のように書いても同じことです。

```rust
    match killer {
        Ok(x) => Ok(x),
        Err(y) => Err(y),
    }
```

これは実質何もしてないので以下のように書いても同じです。

```rust
    killer
```

`killer` は [`remove_dir_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.remove_dir_all.html) の返り値なので型は `Result<(), std::io::Error>` ですから、 `Result<&str, &str>` にはマッチせず、エラーになります。

恐らくやりたいのはok、 errのメッセージを返したいのだと思います。その場合は `remove_dir_all` の返り値は使わないので `_` パターンを使って無視するとよいです。

まとめると、`cleaner` 関数を以下のようにするとよいでしょう。

```rust
fn clener() -> Result<String, String> {
    let killer = fs::remove_dir_all("/tmp");
    let ok = "complete a mission";
    let err = "missing a mission";

    match killer {
        Ok(_) => Ok(ok.to_string()),
        Err(_) => Err(err.to_string()),
    }
}
```

> またデーモンの組み方とは？

一般論としては、2回フォークして不要なリソースを切り離し、カレントディレクトリや標準出入力などを調整すればよいです。[こちらの記事](https://qiita.com/0xfffffff7/items/08d9c268c728da46d20b)が詳しいようなので参考にして下さい。

しかし上記の方法はいささか手間なので別の方法もあります。1つは上記の方法をライブラリ化したものを使う方法、もう1つはsystemdのサービスにして、普通のプログラムをデーモンのように動かす方法です。

ライブラリ化したものは私は使ったことはないのですが、調べるといくつか選択肢があるようです。
https://crates.io/search?q=daemon

systemdを使う方法はこちらの記事を参考にしてみて下さい。
https://qiita.com/DQNEO/items/0b5d0bc5d3cf407cb7ff

以上が参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ひとつだけ質問してもよろしいでしょうか？remove_dir_allのResultは空のタプルのみと見受けられますが、なぜstd::io::Errorを実装していると気づいたのでしょうか？今後の自分の知識発展にご協力ください。お願いします。

Comment: ドキュメントのリンクを辿るとわかります。
標準ライブラリの [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) は `Result<T, E>` で定義されているので `Result<()>` では引数が1つ足りません。Rustのイディオムとして、エラーを固定した `Result` (`type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, SomeError>;` )を定義するのはよくあることなので、 `remove_dir_all` の [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html) をクリックするとその通りであることが分かります。因みに黄色い名前は型エイリアスです。あとは [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html) をクリックすると `std::io::Error` であることがわかります

Comment: ありがとうございます。全て符に落ちました。作成途中の関数もかいあって順調にテストが通りました。ご協力に感謝します。